# Command to change the value of "Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from U.S."

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, default, dotfiles

I'm currently developing my own macOS dotfiles.

I wasn't able to find a command that I can use to change the value of "**Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from U.S.**" I was trying to find it by using the `defaults` command.

I need a command to turn it on.

[image: What I want to change]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one useful trick. In order to find the `defaults` key for this setting, I opened terminal and wrote next command:

```bash
defaults read > 1
```

Then I turned this setting off and executed:

```bash
defaults read > 2
```

And then after we saved 2 files, we can find the difference:

```bash
diff 1 2
```

Here I was trying to find the key in the `defaults` which was affected, and I found it.

Here is a command for changing the value of "**Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from U.S.**":

```bash
# Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from U.S.
defaults write NSGlobalDomain TISRomanSwitchState -int 1
# Possible values: `0` - off, `1` - on
```